# Sections of a polar action are totally geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, group-actions, submanifold

Suppose $G\curvearrowright M$ is an isometric action of a Lie group on a complete Riemannian manifold $M$, and assume it is polar. This means that the action is proper and there exists a closed (hence complete) embedded submanifold $\Sigma\subseteq M$ (called a section) which meets all orbits orthogonally. It is well known that $\Sigma$ is totally geodesic, but I have not found a convincing proof of that fact.

There is a special case where the last statement is easy to prove: the second fundamental form vanishes at regular (and exceptional) points. Indeed, given any $p\in \Sigma$ such that $G\cdot p$ has maximal dimension, $v\in T_{p}(\Sigma)=T_{p}(G\cdot p)$ and $\xi\in T_{p}(G\cdot p)$, we can find an element $X$ in the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$ such that

$$\xi=X^{*}(p), \quad X^{*}(q)=\dfrac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}\operatorname{Exp}(tX)\cdot q.$$

The vector field $X^{*}$ is Killing, so that its covariant derivative is antisymmetric. Let $\mathbb{II}$ be the second fundamental form of $\Sigma$. Then $\mathbb{II}(v,v)$ is tangent to $G\cdot p$ and $\langle \mathbb{II}(v,v),\xi \rangle=-\langle v,\nabla_{v}X^{*} \rangle=0$, so $\mathbb{II}(v,v)=0$. Polarizing, we get $\mathbb{II}=0$.

The usual argument for proving that sections are totally geodesic at all points revolves around the fact that regular points are dense in $\Sigma$. My problem is that all proofs that I found seem to lack crucial details for it. Here are some examples:

1. In "Lie Groups and Geometric Aspects of Isometric Actions", by Alexandrino and Bettiol, it is stated in Exercise 4.9 that the density follows from Kleiner's Lemma (cf Lemma 3.70), but I can't get the connection between the lemma and this fact.
2. In "Critical Point Theory and Submanifold Geometry", by Palais and Terng, the authors state that density follows from the theory of Riemannian submersions, without giving further details.
3. In "Polar Manifolds and Actions", by Grove and Ziller, the authors state that singular points are isolated along any geodesic, because of the Slice Theorem. This is because if $\gamma$ is any geodesic of $\Sigma$, and $t_{0}$ lies in the closure of $\{ t\in \mathbb{R}\colon \gamma(t)\in M_{R} \}$, then $\gamma(t_{0}-\varepsilon)$ and $\gamma(t_{0}+\varepsilon)$ have the same isotropy for sufficiently small $\varepsilon>0$ (again, because of the Slice Theorem), but I don't understand why this is the case.

Could somebody elaborate on any of the methods of proof proposed above (preferably the first or the last), or give a reference to a detailed proof of the fact that regular points are dense?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT

I forgot to mention another method of proof, proposed in the book "Submanifolds and Holonomy", by Berndt, Console and Olmos. I have an (almost full) solution, which needs to prove the following crucial fact: if $p\in \Sigma$ and there is an open subset $\Omega\subseteq \Sigma$ such that all orbits of the points in $\Omega$ have the same (nonprincipal) type, then $T_{p}(\Sigma)$ is pointwise fixed by the slice representation. If somebody could give a proof of this last fact, I would also accept it as an answer.

**EDIT 2**

I've decided to repost this question on MathOverflow. If anyone is interested in seeing it, you can find it on https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398008/sections-of-a-polar-action-are-totally-geodesic

Comment: To be clear, what you want is a proof that the regular points in $\Sigma$ are dense?

Comment: Exactly. That they are dense in $\Sigma$ (with respect to the subspace topology).

Comment: I saw that you cross posted this to Mathoverflow.  I think that's a great idea, but you may want to include a link in this post to that one and vice versa, just so people don't duplicate effort.

Comment: Okay, I'll follow the advice. Thank you very much!